# Referring to an item in an IEnumerable with no ID

Tags: c#

So I may have coded myself into a corner, and I want to know the best way out.

I have this document editor I'm writing, and one property of the documents being edited is a list of structures. The document is stored as XML, so each of these structures is an XML node and its properties. My `Document` class exposes these structures as an IEnumerable.

In my editor, I want to literally highlight these structures when the mouse is nearby. I've already done the task of identifying one close to the cursor. But now I have to be able to refer to that instance of the structure, and store that somewhere. Finding the closest one just iterates through the IEnumerable, and returns the structure itself. I suppose that I could use the structure itself as the reference, but then I'm going to wind up saying in my display code `if (thing == nearestThing)` and it's going to do a hash code comparison or something, right?

That feels like the wrong way to do it, but I don't have a proper ID for these structures either. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know why you would shy away from `(thing == nearestThing)`.  Isn't that a very simple way of testing whether the thing should be highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with that way. Keep in mind though, you should make sure that `==` (and to a greater extend, `Equals` and `GetHashcode`) reliably produce the same results for the same inputs.

Comment: That was basically my concern.